# Group List By Different Types

Tags: java, spring

I have a `List<Foo> foos` and I need to return three lists of `List<Foo>` objects based on different criteria.

To give you an idea, a brute force way to do this would be to filter the complete list by each  criteria and return three different lists:

```
List<Foo> methodA (List<Foo> foo) {
  return foo.stream()
            .filter(lambda1).collect()...
}

List<Foo> methodB (List<Foo> foo) {
  return foo.stream()
            .filter(lambda2)
            .filter(lambda3).collect()...
}

List<Foo> methodC (List<Foo> foo) {
  return foo.stream()
            .filter(lambda2)
            .filter(lambda4).collect()...
}
```

In the end, I need to add all three lists to the same model in Spring.  Is there a better way to do this?

I thought about using `groupingBy`, but then I'd be iterating maps and my sense is that the code would be more involved doing so (and I don't know that time complexity would be lower).

**Update**:
The other piece is that I realized is that `lambda3.negate()` is equivalent to `lambda4`.  No limitation on Java version (using 14).

Comment: I think `groupBy` approach is the best one in terms of performance

Comment: Are using Java 12 or higher? If so a nested `Collectors.teeing` should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 12 or higher you could try `Collectors#teeing`. In order to be able to explain it more easily, let's assume that your foo object is an IT person with the attributes which describe his/her `gender`, `job title`, `years of experience` and if she/he `has a master's degree`.

```
class Foo {
    String gender;
    String profession;
    int expInYears;
    boolean hasAMastersDegree;

    public Foo(String gender, String profession, int expInYears, boolean hasAMaster) {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.expInYears = expInYears;
        this.hasAMastersDegree = hasAMaster;
    }
    //getter, setter toString ... if needed
}
```

So a list of foos could look like something like:

```
List<Foo> list = List.of(
            new Foo("M", "developer",    6,  true),
            new Foo("M", "webdesigner",  2,  false),
            new Foo("W", "testmanager",  1,  true),
            new Foo("M", "developer",    12, false),
            new Foo("M", "IT-Architect", 7,  true),
            new Foo("W", "webdesigner",  6,  false),
            new Foo("W", "developer",    3,  true),
            new Foo("M", "developer",    1,  false));
```

For the sake of completeness, let's also define a few predicates which can correspond to your `lambda1, lambda2 ...`

```
Predicate<Foo> isMale     = f -> f.getGender().equals("M");
Predicate<Foo> isDev      = f -> f.getProfession().equals("developer");
Predicate<Foo> isSenior   = f -> f.getExpInYears() > 5;
Predicate<Foo> hasAMaster = f -> f.hasAMastersDegree();
```

What you are currently doing is, you stream over the same list three times to generate your three different lists.

Suppose the task is to create three lists: a list of all men, a list of developers who have a master's degree and a list of all female senior-it employees. Your current approach:

```
List<Foo> males = list.stream()
            .filter(isMale).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Foo> devsWithMaster = list.stream()
            .filter(isDev.and(hasAMaster))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Foo> femaleSeniors = list.stream()
            .filter(isMale.negate().and(isSenior))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<List<Foo>> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(males);
result.add(devsWithMaster);
result.add(femaleSeniors);
```

As mentioned at the beginning you can use the teeing collector which is available since java twelve for your case, which enables you to iterate only once over the list. First let's create only two of the three lists: males and devs with a master's degree

```
List<List<Foo>> list_of_lists_of_males_and_devsWithMaster = 
            list.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.teeing(
                            Collectors.filtering(isMale, Collectors.toList()), 
                            Collectors.filtering(isDev.and(hasAMaster), Collectors.toList()),
                            (List<Foo> f, List<Foo> g) -> List.of(f, g)));
```

For three lists you just need to nest the teeing collector, and still need to stream only once over your list: lets add to the list of lists a list of female senior employees

```
List<List<Foo>> allLists = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.teeing(
                    Collectors.teeing(
                            Collectors.filtering(isMale, Collectors.toList()),
                            Collectors.filtering(isDev.and(hasAMaster), Collectors.toList()),
                            (List<Foo> f, List<Foo> g) -> List.of(f, g)),
                    Collectors.filtering(isMale.negate().and(isSenior), Collectors.toList()),
                    (List<List<Foo>> f1, List<Foo> f2) -> {
                        List<List<Foo>> fo = new ArrayList<>();
                        fo.addAll(f1);
                        fo.add(f2);
                        return fo;                           
                    }
            ));
```

This post has become much longer than expected. Here's a potato:

```
System.out.println("POTATO");
```

Comment: I am thinking I can also create a wrapper instead of returning a list of lists since I'll need to provide the three lists separately on the front-end and know which one is which.  But this concept can still apply.  Nice job on the potato.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having three different methods, you could have one generic method like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Foo> foo = ...;
    Stream<Foo> stream1 = filteredStream(foo, predicate1);
    Stream<Foo> stream2 = filteredStream(foo, predicate2.and(predicate3));
    Stream<Foo> stream3 = filteredStream(foo, predicate2.and(predicate4));
}

static Stream<Foo> filteredStream(List<Foo> foo, Predicate<Foo> predicate) {
    return foo.stream().filter(predicate);
}
```

You can work on the streams combine them based on filtering criteria or combine all of them using `Stream.of()`

Answer (score 0):

A better way is quite a general statement. The way you mentioned might not be the most efficient but it is very simple, testable, and easy to change which is important.

If we're talking efficiency then you can improve it by:

1. Using parallelStream instead of stream as you don't care about the order.
2. Call methodA, methodB and methodC each in their own thread. But foo will need to be a threadsafe list implementation

Answer (score 0):

I would personally choose the approach you suggested, using `groupingBy`:

```
final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> data = Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> {
      if (i >= 0 && i < 5) {
          return 0;
      } else if (i >= 5 && i < 8) {
          return 1;
      } else if (i >= 8) {
          return 2;
      }
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to classify!");
   }));
```

Of course this is an example and can be implemented in a more elegant way.

As I understood, you need to have 3 different lists - so, the above code does that in 1 pass. And roughly, it has an `O(n)` complexity, which is the minimum possible one for your problem, because you have to visit all the elements of the list.